# make a div go off screen when a checkbox is unchecked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a div go off screen when I uncheck a checkbox, it works fine when I check the box, but not when I uncheck it.

here is the JavaScript code:

```
function slide() {

    const button = document.getElementById('menucheck');
    const sidebar = document.getElementById('side');

    if (button.checked) {
        sidebar.style.left = 0;
    } else {
        sidebar.style.left = -250;
    }

}
```

Comment: When you debug, what specifically fails?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Its the else statement. So I have a div and a checkbox, I'm trying to move the div to the left when the checkbox is checked, and to the right when its unchecked. Is that enough for you?

Comment: When I debug the div only moves to 0 on the left, all other positions don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `left` style property needs units, not just a number:

```
sidebar.style.left = '-250px';
```

Example:

```js
function slide() {

    const button = document.getElementById('menucheck');
    const sidebar = document.getElementById('side');

    console.log(button.checked);
    if (button.checked) {
        sidebar.style.left = 0;
    } else {
        sidebar.style.left = '-250px';
    }

}

document.querySelector('#menucheck').addEventListener('change', slide);
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: -250px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="menucheck" />
<div id="side">test</div>
```